# Django Channels over apache server

Tags: django, apache, django-channels

I have a Django project that's working well on my VPS over apache.
after adding Django channels to my project it's working on localhost perfectly but in my vps, my browser logged an error "WebSocket connection to '...' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404" and the project failed.

according to my googling, I think apache can't support web-socket. but can't find a clear answer and trip for running channels on apache

this is my apache config in 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static /opt/kalameh/static
<Directory /opt/kalameh/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/kalameh/server>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


WSGIDaemonProcess kalameh python-path=opt/kalameh python-home=opt/kalameh/kalamehenv
WSGIProcessGroup kalameh
WSGIScriptAlias / opt/kalameh/server/wsgi.py

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is my wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/opt/kalameh/')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings")


application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: I guess that you have to add you domain name/ip address to the CHANNEL_LAYERS -> CONFIG -> hosts

Comment: i try this but not solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to check [channels' Deploying section](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Be aware the slight differences between channels [v1.x](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/deploying.html#) and [v.2x](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html) documentation. Pick up the appropriate one.

As you notice, Apache does not support websocket. So you would need to run a server that exposes websocket - `a native ASGI interface server` (terminology used by channel documentation). You can use [Django's Daphne](http://github.com/django/daphne/). Daphne also supports HTTP interface.

So you have two solutions:

1. Keep Apache delivering your Django's HTTP request + Daphne delivering your websocket (if you go for this solution, the keywords to use to find more documentation are `reverse proxy` and `ProxyPass`)
2. Using Daphne for delivering your Websocket and HTTP (no need of Apache).